# Using Glue to transform CSV file from S3 bucket and saving the transformed data back into another S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

Objective is to transform the data (csv files) from one S3 bucket to another S3 bucket - using Glue.

What I already tried:

1. I created a CSV classifier.
2. I created a crawler which scans the data coming in S3 bucket.

Where I am stuck:

1. Unable to find how can we store the output in S3 again without saving it in any RDS or other database services.

Because Glue output is asking for database output, which I don't have and don't want to use.

Is there any way I can achieve the goal without using any other DB system, just plain - S3, Glue?

## More Information

Sample single CSV file, I am trying to merge

[image]

Classifier with delimeter of ";"

[image]

Crawler Configuration

[image]

Crawler Result (No schema detected)

[image]

Comment: in which format you want to save your output? and are you performing any transformation on source data?

Comment: @AchyutVyas the format will be same CSV. I just want to merge multiple CSV files from S3 and create a CSV file combined (of all those indivisual files) with an header.

Comment: First, your Crawler include path is s3 folder path not s3 source file path

Comment: @AchyutVyas the crawler is pointing to the CSV file (if you refer to include path field in shared image), what do you mean source file path? This is the CSV file I want to extract schema from isn't them this will be source file?

Comment: take a look in [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/define-crawler.html#crawler-data-stores-exclude) _For Amazon S3 data stores, the syntax is bucket-name/folder-name/file-name.ext. To crawl all objects in a bucket, you specify just the bucket name in the include path_

That means in your Crawler property **include path** value must be **s3://dz-test**

Comment: @AchyutVyas but I have other files in that bucket. I don't want schema extraction from those files. As per the documentation as well if we are parsing just one file we use (bucket-name/folder-name/file-name.ext) which is the current value of include path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221223/discussion-between-kumar-vivek-and-achyut-vyas).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that all CSV files which you want to merge have the same schema.
**You can write the same code in Glue which you write in local Spark deployment**

**Step 1: Get data from Catalog table**

```
val datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "database_name", table_name = "table_name", transformation_ctx = "datasource0")
```

**Step 2: Convert datasource0 dynamic frame to data Frame**

```
val df = datasource0.toDF()
```

**Step 3: Store data frame to target s3 bucket**

```
df.write.format("csv").mode("append").save("s3://target-s3-path/Output")
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to glue, but what do you mean by Spark deployment? At the moment I just have created the crawler and classifier if I run the crawller I don't see any schema in Database (Table).

Am I missing something?

Comment: I think you haven't configured your Crawler properly, make sure the crawler pointing to the s3 folder, not the source file. will you please share your Crawler info.
for Spark deployment, what I mean is that you can write same code in spark and glue.
the code is almost same.

Comment: I updated the question with my setup of crawler and sample CSV file. I made sure, that I am pointing to the source file rather than S3 folder itself.

got the fact that we can use spark and glue code, but do we need a spark script for this manipulation and where do we add that script?